# Outlook 2010 with Exchange Online

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, office365

Does Outlook2010/2013interface with anything other than IMAP or Pop3? If so how? While manual configuration of imap works, the autodiscover wizard is turning up nothing. I have the cname on my 1and1.com pointed to www.mydomain.us. The manual setup for Outlook.com or compatible prompts for a server. Is that supposed to be the same server as specified for the imap?
I am hoping that setup for Outlook clients on pc and laptops is as seamless as it is when the pc/laptop is on a LAN. Can Outlook Anywhere (over https/rpc) be used? If so, how does one obtain the proxy server names and settings?

When it is all setup will the enduser experiance emulate that of Outlook and Exchange 2010 in regards to calender sharing and contacts?

Thankyou for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what 1and1.com offers, however you can only use OutlookAnywhere (RPC-over-HTTP) with Exchange 2003-2013.

Outlook 2003-2013 can use IMAP, POP, Exchange MAPI (RPC).  With add-ons you may be able to support other protocols, but I've never used any.

For autodiscover to work,  you'll usually need Exchange although there are some ways to generate the autodiscover XML without Exchange.  Outlook 2010-13 (and I think 2007 too) can try guess the settings for IMAP/POP settings based on your email address, but the server would have to use pretty standard hostnames and ports for it to guess correctly.

IMAP and POP only support email message types and will not sync contacts and calendars between the server and the Outlook client, not natively anyway.

Comment: • Outlook Anywhere: Outlook Anywhere lets Outlook users connect to Exchange Server and Exchange Online Archiving over the Internet with no need for a VPN connection. Communication between Outlook and Exchange Online Archiving occurs via an SSL-secured tunnel, using the RPC-over-HTTP Windows networking component.
•http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13602

Comment: The above is from a Micsoft published document but I still cannot find documentation on how to setup Outlook Anywhere or Outlook RPC over Http.  It seems to rely on Autodiscover and if that does not work you are out of business.

Comment: From your original question, it sounds like you do not have Exchange.  If that is the case, you cannot use RPC-over-HTTP (aka OutlookAnywhere), even if you try to set it up manually.

Comment: However, if you do have Exchange 2003+, you can try to setup Outlook manually to use RPC-over-HTTP, assuming that the admin has allowed it.  In Outlook, when you setup the Exchange connection in the profile, go to the Connections tab (advanced settings) and setup the proxy settings.  In most cases, the proxy server is the same as the OWA server, but it does not have to be.